# Parallel GNU Make runs command multiple times for Antlr parser generation files

Tags: build, makefile, parallel-processing, antlr, gnu

I have a makefile rule to generate the output files of an antlr parser:

```
XLexer.c XLexer.h XParser.c XParser.h X.tokens: X.g
    $(ANTLR) $(ANTLRFLAGS) X.g
```

This works fine and rebuilds all of the resulting files when X.g is changed, as expected.  But when I run parallel make with the -j flag, the above rule is run once for every file, so in this case the antlr call is run 5 times in parallel.

Is there a way to do this type of rule but only have the command run once?  I know about the .NOPARALLEL: rule but that defeats the purpose.  I have attempted to use a lockfile to cause the multiple runs to exit if one is already running but with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless all the output files share a common stem (eg, "XLexer.c" and "XLexer.h" have the stem "XLexer"), there is no clean way to do this in GNU make.  There are a variety of workarounds, such as using a sentinel file:

```
XLexer.c XLexer.h XParser.c XParser.h X.tokens: dummy
    @

dummy: X.g
    $(ANTLR) $(ANTLRFLAGS) X.g && touch dummy
```

There's a thorough write-up of the options in the [Rules with Multiple Outputs in GNU Make](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/ask-mr-make/12908-rules-with-multiple-outputs-in-gnu-make) article on the Mr. Make column at CMCrossroads.

(The "@" line is a "no-op" command, but it's important: Without it, GNU make would assume  that `XLexer.c` and friends are never updated by incremental rebuilds, so you'd have to run make twice for any change in X.g to take effect)

Alternatively, you could use a smarter version of make, like [ElectricAccelerator](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator-dev.php), which would automatically solve this problem for you (disclaimer: I'm the architect of ElectricAccelerator).

Comment: Is there some reason a pattern rule with multiple targets wouldn't work for this?

Comment: @rakslice: pattern rules only work if all output targets have a common stem. In this example you might be able to make a go of it by making X the stem, as in `%Lexer.c %Lexer.h %Parser.c %Parser.h %.tokens: %.g`. It's a bit unusual, but depending on your environment that may be acceptable.

Comment: Is it possible that two or more make jobs could enter the dummy rule simultaneously, before the dummy file is touched? Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm a make noob

Comment: @mercurytw: no, there will be only one instance of the dummy rule.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern rule will behave differently to a plain rule; [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) says:

> Pattern rules may have more than one target. Unlike normal rules, this does not act as many different rules with the same prerequisites and recipe. If a pattern rule has multiple targets, `make` knows that the rule’s recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets.

This will work for your case, because you have a common stem (`X`):

```
all: XLexer.c XLexer.h XParser.c XParser.h X.tokens
# (or more realistically, several targets that depend on the above)

%Lexer.c %Lexer.h %Parser.c %Parser.h %.tokens: %.g
    $(ANTLR) $(ANTLRFLAGS) $<
```